# Raster calc returns only one layers when applied to raster stack

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, calc

I have a raster stack created from daily climate data.  Can be found here:

```
#!/bin/bash 
wget -nc -c -nd http://northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/tmmx_1982.nc
```

The goal is to get the 95th percentile of temperature values per month from these daily records.  Whenever I use `calc` from the `raster` package it just returns one layer instead of 12 (e.g., 12 months)  What am I missing?!

```
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

file = "../data/raw/climate/tmmx_1982.nc " 
rstr <- raster(file)
```

`> rstr
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 585, 1386, 810810, 366  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
extent      : -124.793, -67.043, 25.04186, 49.41686  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       :   layer.1,   layer.2,   layer.3,   layer.4,   layer.5,   layer.6,   layer.7,   layer.8,   layer.9,  layer.10,  layer.11,  layer.12,  layer.13,  layer.14,  layer.15, ... 
min values  : 1.3268673, 0.7221603, 1.8519223, 1.6214808, 0.8629752, 1.1126643, 1.8769895, 0.9587604, 1.7360761, 2.1099827, 2.1147265, 1.8696048, 1.7619936, 2.0253942, 2.6840794, ... 
max values  :  73.20462,  60.35675,  64.68890,  53.11994,  60.15675,  55.91125,  77.29095,  64.39179,  48.26004,  64.70559,  79.85970,  62.31242,  53.89768,  52.15949,  80.23198, ...`

```
date_seq <- date_seq[1:nlayers(rstr)]
month_seq <- month(date_seq)

mean_tmp <- stackApply(rstr, month_seq, fun = mean)
```

`> mean_tmp 
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 585, 1386, 810810, 12  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
extent      : -124.793, -67.043, 25.04186, 49.41686  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /tmp/RtmpYf4pQe/raster/r_tmp_2017-09-25_182536_48012_88372.grd 
names       :  index_1,  index_2,  index_3,  index_4,  index_5,  index_6,  index_7,  index_8,  index_9, index_10, index_11, index_12 
min values  : 4.586111, 5.656802, 6.444234, 6.875973, 6.281896, 4.495534, 5.081545, 4.396824, 4.316368, 6.413400, 4.233641, 3.119827 
max values  : 49.12178, 47.61632, 44.70796, 47.57829, 46.97714, 51.61986, 37.77228, 51.30043, 42.51572, 36.86453, 37.96615, 52.15552`

```
mean_90thtmp <- calc(mean_tmp, forceapply = TRUE, 
                 fun = function(x) {quantile(x, probs = 0.90, na.rm = TRUE) })
```

`> mean_90thtmp
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 585, 1386, 810810  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
extent      : -124.793, -67.043, 25.04186, 49.41686  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 8.84197, 50.52144  (min, max)`

Suggestions are very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You are getting a single layer back because you are calculating the 90th percentile of the monthly means. I'm not quite sure why you are calculating the mean at all. I think instead you need to run the quantile function inside of the stackApply function or inside of a loop where you subset the daily values for each month from the stack. I'm getting an error when I try to use the stackApply approach but I will try a few more ideas and submit an answer.

Comment: ideally it would be the means per day, but since I wasn't able to create monthly images of the 95th percentile I figured I would start by figure out a solution for that.  I tried running the function on the daily images inside of stackApply, but kept returning an error.  I'm truly stuck, any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using a `for` loop:

```
x <- stack() # create an empty stack
for (i in 1:nlayers(mean_tmp)){

mean_90thtmp <- calc(mean_tmp[[i]], forceapply = TRUE, 
                 fun = function(x) {quantile(x, probs = 0.90, na.rm = TRUE) })

x <- stack(x , mean_90thtmp )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was assuming/thinking it was something I was missing inside of the `calc` function because I kept reading in the documentation that in `calc` is able to handle applying a function among all layers.  Especially when `forceapply = TRUE`.  Thanks though - this is some good food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get the `stackApply` function to work with using `quantile` as the function.

Here is a method that uses a loop to select all layers from the stack for each month.

```
library(raster)
rstr <- raster('tmmx_1982.nc')
date_seq <- date_seq[1:nlayers(rstr)]
month_seq <- month(date_seq)

outSt <- stack()
for (mn in 1:12){
  st <- subset(rstr, which(month_seq == mn))
  mn_90th <- calc(st, fun=function(x) raster::quantile(x, probs=0.9, na.rm=T))
  outSt <- addLayer(outSt, mn_90th)
}
```

Comment: it is so strange that you cannot use stackApply or calc natively with the quantile function over each layer in a raster stack.  Thanks for this solution, and verifying that the stackApply issue was not just me!  Most appreciated.